# how to output a list of requests from basecamp classic api using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, basecamp

I'd like to output a list of projects with the basecamp classic api using node. Basically how to use the basecamp classic api using node. I've come across [this modules](https://www.npmjs.org/package/basecamp-classic) example. But need a little more direction on how to implement it.

```
var Basecamp = require('basecamp-classic');

var bc = new Basecamp(
  'https://YOUR_COMPANY.basecamphq.com',
  'YOUR_API_KEY'
);

module.exports = function(req, res) {
  bc.todoLists.all(function(err, lists){
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.send('there was a problem');
    } else {
      // render the todo template and pass it our lists object
      res.render('todo', {
        todoLists: lists
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Do you have any more specific question? I'm using the same module and it works fine. Did you have success in what you were trying to do?